# Is there a faster convergence series than the Taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am looking for a series expansion which will converge faster than the Taylor series. I mean
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
$$

For some function you may need large $N$ to get a convergent series. Is there a faster convergent series?

Comment: depends on the function.

Comment: For some functions, its Taylor series won't converge to the function at more than one point

Comment: the series $f,0,0,0\dots$  converges really fast.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling haha

Comment: some times one can re-cast the Taylor to a sum of Chebyshev polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials...

Comment: Yes there is a faster convergence.

Comment: You can try Padé approximation (using a rational function instead of a polynomial): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant.